# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nvidia'

Tags: python, tensorflow, conda

I've been trying to install tensorflow with pip following this [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip): but when I try to configure the system paths with this command,

`CUDNN_PATH=$(dirname $(python -c "import nvidia.cudnn;print(nvidia.cudnn.__file__)")) export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$CONDA_PREFIX/lib/:$CUDNN_PATH/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH`

Python says there is no module named `nvidia`, although I made sure that I installed `nvidia-cublas-cu11`, `nvidia-cudnn-cu11`, `nvidia-dali-cuda110`, and `nvidia-pyindex`, as shown on my conda list in the base environment.

also the command `nvcc` does not work even though I installed cuda.

What's wrong?

installing cuda and nvidia-dali multiple times on both pip and conda

Comment: Have you installed CUDA from the [official site](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads)? And have you installed the right version? The [current one is 11.8](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu).

Comment: It could be that `pip` installed the packages for some other version of python on your system.

Comment: Show us the output of `pip show nvidia-cublas-cu11`, specifically the `Location` line, and also the output of `python -c "import sys; print(sys.path)"`

Comment: @john-gordon `Version: 11.11.3.6`, `Location: /home/[username]/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages` for the first one, and `['', '/usr/lib64/python311.zip', '/usr/lib64/python3.11', '/usr/lib64/python3.11/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib64/python3.11/site-packages', '/usr/lib/python3.11/site-packages']` for the second one.

Comment: @kggn I tried installing CUDA from the official site as well.

Comment: Well, that's the problem.  `pip` is using `home/[username]/anaconda3/lib/python3.11`, but `python` is using `/usr/lib64/python3.11` and `/usr/lib/python3.11`.

Comment: @john-gordon should I install `pip` on `/usr/lib/python3.11` or should i edit PATH so that it uses the one in anaconda3 by default?

Comment: I haven't used anaconda.  What is the correct way to run python code with anaconda?  Is `python` still the command you're supposed to use?  Or is it some other command?

Comment: Probably editing PATH to use the one in anaconda3 would be a good solution.